# How to send web stream from react-native to tensor-flow library?

Tags: javascript, react-native, webrtc

I am trying to build a nsfw stream detection webcam service. I have implemented this already in pure react js by accessing the canvas element to grab individual frames and send them to the model. However, in react-native there is no canvas element, and the next best thing is a react-native-video element, but that package does not support extraction of individual frames.

```
 mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: true,
    video: {
      width: 640,
      height: 480,
      frameRate: 30,
      facingMode: (isFront ? "user" : "environment"),
      deviceId: videoSourceId
    }
  })
  .then(stream => {
    // Got stream!
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // Log error
  });
```

This code block is what begins the stream, yet logging the stream provides no actual data about the frames, or where to access them. The image frames must be somewhere in the code in order to be rendered I am completely lost in where to look for them. Any tips or advice is appreciated.